# Find elements of given matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array, data-structures

You are given an infinite matrix whose upper-left square starts with 1. Here are the first five rows of the infinite matrix :

```
 1  2  9 10 25
 4  3  8 11 24
 5  6  7 12 23
16 15 14 13 22
17 18 19 20 21
```

Your task is to find out the number in presents at row x and column y after observing a certain kind of patter present in the matrix

Input Format
The first input line contains an integer t: the number of test cases
After this, there are t lines, each containing integer x and y

For each test, print the number present at xth row and yth column.
sample input
3
2 3
1 1
4 2
sample output
8
1
15

Comment: And what is your question about this assignment?

Comment: how to find the element of the matrix  on given indexes without iterating through the matix because we don,t know the size

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am thinking in the way of the column and rows type is column is even or odd like that but I m not able to find the correct approach

Comment: This, as most questions which give a strong impression of being a blind homework dump, lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying yourself. To improve have a look at the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the numbers at the right and bottom border of a left upper square are consecutive (going either down and left, or right and up). First determine in which border your position is, then find out which direction applies, and finally find the correct number at the position (which easy formula gives you the first number in the border?).

Comment: no given fromula only the given infinite matrix

Comment: I meant, you should find one (it is really easy).

Comment: I am not getting the correct logic/ approach...... can you help me??

Comment: At which of my three steps are you stuck?